# Changing font on line items in Table of Contents

Tags: fonts, biblatex, table-of-contents, babel

I am currently finishing my thesis and have run into a few formatting problems. Typically, I am able to find an existing solution either here or another Latex community. However, I am currently dealing with an issue that I am having trouble finding existing solutions for. These questions are related to the List of Tables, List of Figures, References, and Appendix sections as shown in the table of contents.

For the List of Tables, List of Figures, and References, the font size for those headings is larger than than other chapter headings. For the Appendix, I would like to unbold the heading and make it all caps. The two below screenshots show my problem:
[image]
[image]

My thesis is using the report class with a macros specified by a third party .cls file for my university. The References heading was added by using the option `[heading=bibintoc]` in the `\printbiblography` command from the biblatex package. The list of tables and list of figures were added by modifying the .cls file in the appropriate location to add a table of content line for each list using the following code:

```
\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}\listoftables
```

and

```
\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}\listoffigures
```

The heading names are defined by modified babel macros. I am also using the following packages in my thesis to effect other formatting changes:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titletoc}
```

How can I change the font of these line items in the table of contents? I would prefer to use base latex commands or a package I already have.

Comment: It might be hard to come up with a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) in  your case here, but it will greatly increase your chances of getting a good answer that helps you. Currently we can't see the code that modifies the toc to look like this in your document.

Comment: can you please show us the definition of `\listtablename`?

Comment: and how did you add the appendix  heading to  the toc?

Comment: Any news here? We will at least need to see the additional information touhami asked for in order to be able to help you effectively.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, but I managed to fix the problem on my own. In attempting to create an MWE from the .cls file, I found the specific macros that created the List of Figures and the List of Tables. I modified the commands that created the content lines to be as follows:

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\normalsize\listfigurename}\listoffigures